# How to assign object properties to the result of an XMLHTTP Request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm writing a Reversi engine and I want to be able to fetch the opening book from a file on the server and then assign this as an array to the 'openings' property of the Reversi class. At the moment I have assigned it to the 'openings' property of the reversi object, which is the (only) instance of the Reversi class. However, I feel as though this is a bad solution and a better one must exist.

I've tried using the `this` keyword but it does not refer to the Reversi class in this context.

```
class Reversi {

    constructor(dims) {
        this.board = new Board(dims)
        this.display = new Display(dims)
        this.gameRunning = true
        this.blackTurn = true
        this.missedTurns = 0
        this.humanPlayers = []
        // this.blackPlayer = document.getElementById("engineSelect").value
        this.blackPlayer = "human"
        this.redPlayer = "human"
        this.aiDelay = 200 //miliseconds
        this.freeTiles = dims**2 - 4
        this.gameHistory = ""
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'openings', {
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: []
        })
    }

    loadOpenings(callback) {
        let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                callback(this)
                }
            }
        xhttp.open("GET", "books/openings.txt", true)
        xhttp.send()
    }

    callback(xhttp) {
        let openings = xhttp.responseText.split("\n")
        for (let i = 0; i < openings.length; i++) {
            console.log(openings[i])
            openings[i] = openings[i].split(", ")
        }
        reversi.openings = openings
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` won't work inside callback functions , one idea is to create a setter method that binds to the class, and then call it inside the callback. This would be the final code :

```
class Reversi {

constructor(dims) {
    this.board = new Board(dims)
    this.display = new Display(dims)
    this.gameRunning = true
    this.blackTurn = true
    this.missedTurns = 0
    this.humanPlayers = []
    // this.blackPlayer = document.getElementById("engineSelect").value
    this.blackPlayer = "human"
    this.redPlayer = "human"
    this.aiDelay = 200 //miliseconds
    this.freeTiles = dims**2 - 4
    this.gameHistory = ""
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'openings', {
        configurable: true,  
        writable: true,
        value: []
    })
    this.openings = []
}

loadOpenings(callback) {
    //this is very important
    var that = this
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            callback(this, that)
            }
        }
    xhttp.open("GET", "books/openings.txt", true)
    xhttp.send()
}

setOpenings(openings) {
   this.openings = openings;
}

callback(xhttp, that) {
    let openings = xhttp.responseText.split("\n")
    for (let i = 0; i < openings.length; i++) {
        console.log(openings[i])
        openings[i] = openings[i].split(", ")
    }
    //reversi.openings = openings
    that.setOpenings(openings)
}
```

This may sound crazy, but might work! :)
Here is what I did : 
When you refere `this` inside a callback, it refers to the context of callback function, not the parent class itself. In your code, it does not refer to Reversi, but outside the callback, `this` refers to the Reversi class, so I copied the reference of `this` to a variable `that`, so now `that` permanently has the reference of the class, now I defined a method called `setOpenings()` and I am binding it to Reversi class. 
So , inside callback using `that` variable we can access members of `Reversi` class, Hope you got it!